# Can not push on GIT on Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gitlab

I register on git web site and create a project named Book.this was repo address`https://xxxxxxx@gitlab.com/xxxxxxx/Book.git/`
and on android studio I pushed my project to git. for a reason, I deleted this project from git site not android studio.now I create another project with this repo:`https://xxxx@gitlab.com/xxxxxx/Thread.git` but when I am pushing my project I got this error:

```
manifest@manifest-System:~/AndroidStudioProjects/Book-ThreadExample$ git        push -u origin master
Password for 'https://xxxxxx@gitlab.com': 
remote: Not Found
fatal: repository 'https://xxxxxx@gitlab.com/xxxxxx/Book.git/' not found
```

Actually Book.git has been deleted before .how can I change repo? or solve the problem?

I use this command for add remote but I got another error:

```
git remote add origin https://xxxxxx@gitlab.com/xxxxx/Thread.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

I am using git on android studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I solved my problem.**

The error "remote origin already exists" means what it says: I am trying to add a remote with the same name as one that already exists. I need to either delete it first with `git remote rm origin`, or use `git remote set-url` to change the URL of the existing remote.